# org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;) due to JsonException: Attempting to close incomplete json stream

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the above Json exception after I updated my TestNG to 6.14.3 and Selenium to 3.13.0. I am using ChromeDriver() for my automation. Here's a brief idea about my code:

```
@BeforeSuite:
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chrome driver");

@BeforeMethod:
driver = new ChromeDriver();

@AfterMethod:
driver.quit();
```

My previous Versions were 6.11.0 and 3.7.1 respectively for TestNG and Selenium.

The exception is coming when the code tries to start a WebDriver session.

The full exception is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput;
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.writeTo(NewSessionPayload.java:247)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:69)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:523)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
  at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Suppressed: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Attempting to close incomplete json stream
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.close(JsonOutput.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.writeTo(NewSessionPayload.java:270)
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I think the issue is coming from somewhere other than from the code you've posted. You're receiving a `NoSuchMethodError`, meaning somewhere in your code you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist (for the object that's calling it).

Comment: did you update all selenium components to 3.13? looks like some library (probably selenium-java) is not latest

Comment: The thing is the browser is not starting. I have updated all the dependencies to the latest ones. I think NoSuchMethod error is coming because JsonOutput.write is not being found at runtime. And it looks like driver is depending on library containing this class. I can't figure out which dependency might resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput;
.
Suppressed: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Attempting to close incomplete json stream
```

...implies that **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** was raised while JVM was trying to escape some characters.

It's pretty tough to analyze the error in absence of the following information pertaining to your *Test Environment*:

- **selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar** or **selenium-java-3.13.0** client.
- **JARs** or **Maven** or **Gradle**

But this error is coming out of the following source code:

```
  public void close() {
    if (appendable instanceof Closeable) {
      try {
    ((Closeable) appendable).close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new JsonException(e);
      }
    }

    if (!(stack.getFirst() instanceof Empty)) {
      throw new JsonException("Attempting to close incomplete json stream");
    }
  }
```

### Reason

The possible reason can be one of the following:

- Presence of multiple *Selenium related jars* through **selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar** and **selenium-java-3.13.0** client jars.
- Presence of multiple *Selenium related jars* through **JARs** and **Maven** and/or **Gradle**.
- Presence of **gson-2.8.2.jar** as the [Release Notes of Selenium v3.13.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) clearly mentions:

  ```
  * Introduced our own JSON parser and outputter, allowing GSON to be removed from our dependencies.
  ```

### Solution

- If using manually downloaded **JAR** files, remove all the *Selenium* related *External JARs* and add the newly downloaded one.
- If using **Maven** or **Gradle**, perform the following steps:

  - Through CLI: `mvn clean` (to flush out previous dependencies)
  - Through CLI: `mvn install` (to install the necessary dependencies)
  - Through CLI: `mvn test` (to execute testsuite)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I just performed the exact same steps that you suggested just 15 mins ago and it worked. Sorry I didn't provide an update earlier. But very nice explanation though. I had called the selenium dependency in pom file and also it was present in the external jar list. So I removed all the jars which were present in the external jar list and performed the Maven clean, install and test. Thanks again for the solution. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it use follow config

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below dependencies and it should resolve your problem.

Do not forget to rebuild.

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
```