# org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; due to java.io.IOException: Incomplete document

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, appium, appium-android

I'm creating a new test framework from scratch using Spring Boot 2 and Appium. To write the tests I'm using JUnit which is already included in Spring Boot's `spring-boot-starter-test` POM along with many others. I added Appium to my POM and it now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.automationexperiment</groupId>
    <artifactId>one</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As for my tests, I have a DriverSetup class that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DriverSetup {

  protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "DeviceName");
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.google.android.gm");
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".ConversationListActivityGmail");
    URL myUrl = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    this.driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(myUrl, capabilities);
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

Finally, I have another class that extends from DriverSetup to make sure driver initialization is done before every test. It looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FirstTryTest extends DriverSetup {

  public FirstTryTest() { }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

I just want to make sure I can reach the test in my `FirstTryTest`, but every time the code initializes the AndroidDriver with the `URL` and the `DesiredCapabilities`, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput;
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.writeTo(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:265)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:175)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:93)
    at com.automationexperiment.one.driversetup.DriverSetup.setUp(DriverSetup.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.CustomizedJUnitCoreRunner.run(CustomizedJUnitCoreRunner.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.JUnitLauncher.execute(JUnitLauncher.java:26)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.JUnitLauncher.main(JUnitLauncher.java:15)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:559)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.close(JsonOutput.java:39)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.writeTo(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:288)
        ... 41 more
```

I've tried using an older version of Appium (5.0.4) but it didn't work. I'd like to emphasize the end of the StackTrace. An `IOException` is mentioned while in other questions with similar errors script fails due to a 
 org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084484/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-json-jsonoutput-writeljava-lan)

Comment: Ahh. I had already visited that question. See, my error differs from that one. A the bottom of the one I'm describing, it mentions something about and IOException, while the one you link describes a `org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException`. I tried reproducing the answers they give in that link and none worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput;
.
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document
```

...implies that **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** was raised by the *JVM*.

You have mentioned about using an older version of **Appium v5.0.4**

It's pretty tough to analyze the error in absence of the following information pertaining to your Test Environment:

- Appium server version
- Desktop OS/version
- Mobile platform/version under test
- Real device or emulator/simulator

As per the discussions [Error while running Appium script with AndroidDriver](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10894) and [iOS :Could not initialize the ios capabilities with 6.0.0](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/954)  this error seems to be coming from the **NumberCoercer** Class which have been modified in **Selenium RemoteDriver v3.12.0** to accept **Port** as **`Integer`** while earlier it was accepting `String`.

### Solution

- Update to the latest **Appium Java Client v6.1.0**
- Update to the latest (atleast) **Selenium v3.12.0**
- @SrinivasanTarget mentions one important aspect that:

  - > Appium's Java client comes along with Selenium Dependency so we don't recommend to exclude selenium and add as separate dependency as it may raise conflicts at times.

Here you will find a relevant discussion on [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084484/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-json-jsonoutput-writeljava-lan)

Comment: Many thanks @DebanjanB . I had not crossed into that [iOS:Could not initialize the ios capabilities with 6.0.0](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10894) article but adding both Appium's latest and Selenium's latest version solved the issue. It's still weird to me why wouldn't Appium's latest version target a Selenium version that works with theirs.... But anyway, it works. Thanks!