# Appium drag and drop with ionic Hybrid app

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been having trouble trying to drag and drop an element using Appium to automate an Ionic app. Since it's a hybrid app, at the beggining of each test I switch the context to webview and I wonder if that has something to do with the errors I'm getting.

Some important things I'd like to emphasize:

- I'm using Appium's Java client v6.1.0
- I'm using Selenium's Java client v3.14.0

  - The reason why I'm using both Appium and Selenium is because of an error I was getting trying to run tests which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086405/org-openqa-selenium-json-jsonoutput-writeljava-lang-objectlorg-openqa-seleniu)
- Since I'm planning to test this app in both Android and iOS, I'm declaring my driver as an `AppiumDriver` with the type argument `WebElement`: `AppiumDriver<WebElement>`.

Clicks and isDisplayed methods work fine if used directly from the WebElements I find, but when I try to use Selenium's `Action.dragAndDropBy()` method as the following:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(anyLocator);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.dragAndDropBy(element, offset, 0).build().perform(); // Just want to slide to the right a little
```

I get this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 501 - "unimplemented command: session/a7caba7c406e024951d9bf5b8e5329c9/actions"
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'LSTKMY110732', ip: '10.77.28.235', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: .MainActivity, appPackage: com.myexample.package, autoWebview: true, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: .MainActivity, appPackage: com.myexample.package, autoWebview: true, deviceName: MyDeviceName, newCommandTimeout: 600, platformName: android, platformVersion: 6.0.1}, deviceManufacturer: Xiaomi, deviceModel: Redmi 3S, deviceName: d6bdaa0f7d43, deviceScreenSize: 720x1280, deviceUDID: d6bdaa0f7d43, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 600, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 6.0.1, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: ede1d75f-8c3b-4bb0-b450-da0e712beade
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:640)
    at com.package.companionapp.pageobjects.TransferCreditTileModalPage.setCreditQuantity(TransferCreditTileModalPage.java:41)
    at com.package.companionapp.testclasses.MOBX74Test.testSettingCreditsTile(MOBX74Test.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

If I instead try to use Appium's TouchAction as this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(anyLocator);
int upperLeftX = element.getLocation().getX();
int upperLeftY = element.getLocation().getY();
int width = element.getSize().getWidth();
int height = element.getSize().getHeight();
PointOption center = PointOption.point(upperLeftX + (width / 2), upperLeftY + (height / 2));
PointOption offset = PointOption.point((upperLeftX + (width / 2)) + quantity, upperLeftY + (height / 2));
new TouchAction<>(driver).press(center).moveTo(offset).release().perform();
```

I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'LSTKMY110732', ip: '10.77.28.235', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: .MainActivity, appPackage: com.myexample.package, autoWebview: true, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: .MainActivity, appPackage: com.myexample.package, autoWebview: true, deviceName: Samsung Galaxy S7 edge, newCommandTimeout: 600, platformName: android, platformVersion: 8.0.0}, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-G935U, deviceName: 046897dc, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2560, deviceUDID: 046897dc, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 600, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 8.0.0, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 77d0bc59-1bf6-45c2-931a-882f13e2ee3f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions.performTouchAction(PerformsTouchActions.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.TouchAction.perform(TouchAction.java:187)
    at com.package.companionapp.pageobjects.TransferCreditTileModalPage.setCreditQuantity(TransferCreditTileModalPage.java:49)
    at com.package.companionapp.testclasses.MOBX74Test.testSettingCreditsTile(MOBX74Test.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

If there's some other info that might be useful and I didn't provide, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

It's better that you use `AndroidDriver` instead of `AppiumDriver` for Android and `IOSDriver` for iOS. Also use `AndroidTouchAction` instead of `TouchAction` class for Android as in iOS, you'll have to use JavaScript executor to use Touch gestures. Same is also explained on the [official documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/) site for Appium.